# Can task be synthesized when it uses @(posedge clk)?

Tags: system-verilog

I want to create a task in SystemVerilog that:

1. Consumes time,
2. Does so by using `posedge clk`, and
3. Is synthesizable.

I intend to call it from the clocked output driver for an FSM. For example:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                          My Task
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
task my_task;
  x <= 1'b1;
  @(posedge clk);
  x <= 1'b0;  
endtask

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                      Next State Logic
//
// State changes immediate before & after call to task, in case it matters.
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
always @(posedge clk) begin 
  if (rst == 1'b1) begin 
    state <= RESET;
  end else begin 
    case (state):
      RESET: if (start == 1'b1) state <= STATE_1;
      STATE_1: state <= STATE_2;
      ...
      STATE_42: state <= STATE_43;
      STATE_43: state <= RESET;
    endcase
  end
end

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                      Output Driver
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
always @(posedge clk) begin 
  case (state):
    RESET: x <= 1'b0;
    STATE_1: do_whatever();
    ...
    STATE_42: my_task();
    STATE_43: do_whatever();
  endcase
end
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Does it confuse most synthesizers?

Comment: It is definitely possible  as some tools used to support it. But most tools in use today have chosen not to support more advance behavioral synthesis and stick with RTL.

Comment: Do you know what the motivation was for dropping that feature?

Comment: Among other things, it requires a separate process for modeling reset as well as dealing with "implicit" resets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that task will synthesize properly with any tool.  Synthesis tools recognize specific Verilog code patterns, but that code does not fit any common patterns.  It is best to adhere to patterns such as the examples shown in [synthesizable constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs).  The synthesis tool needs to be able to recognize certain patterns in order to map the behavioral Verilog code to common gate types that are part of a standard cell library (like D flip-flops).

The `always` block looks fine: it is triggered of the `posegde` of `clk`.  But, when you call the task, it triggers off *another* `posedge` of `clk`.  That does not map to any common logic gates.